# Laravel multiple parameters in Route middelware not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-middleware

I have problem that using multiple parameters in my `Route::middleware` isn't working for me. I am trying to assign a specific route only accessible for a *superuser* and *admin* role.

When I just use:

```
role:superuser
```

it works fine, but when I add a second parameter like:

```
role:superuser,admin
```

it fails when I assign myself the *admin* role but still works for the *superuser* role.

I am confused so any help would be appreciated!

---

**Here is my RoleMiddleware:**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RoleMiddleware 
{ 

/** 
* Handle an incoming request. 
* 
* @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request 
* @param \Closure $next 
* @param string $roles 
* @return mixed 
*/ 

public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles) 
{ 
    $user = $request->user();

    if ($user && $user->isSuperuser($roles)) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/home')->withError('U heeft niet de juiste rechten!');

    }
}
```

**Here is my isSuperuser method in my User model:**

```
public function isSuperuser(...$roles)
{
    if ($roles) {
        return $this->roles == $roles;
    }

    return $this->roles;
}
```

**Last but not least my routes/web code for the middleware:**

```
Route::get('/users', 'UsersController@index')->middleware(['role:superuser,admin']);
```

Btw: the method is called `'isSuperuser'` but that's just a name. It also has to accept the *admin* role at some point.

Comment: To apply multiple middleware to a route I think you must add items to an array. I.e ....->middleware(['role:superuser', 'role:admin']);

Answer (score 0):

use `|` instead of `,` like this:

```
Route::get('/users', 'UsersController@index')->middleware(['role:superuser|admin']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it's not working unfortunately.